# Can't create / Events button not visible from the Designer or Source in the .ascx

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, controls

I have a web form user control (.ascx) and for some reason I can't create an event handler for a button.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="cuTheControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="proyectName.Controls.cuTheControl" %>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">

<asp:Table ID="cssForTable" runat="server" Height="20px" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" Width="232px" style="border-collapse: separate;">
    <asp:TableRow ID="cssForRow">
        <asp:TableCell CssClass="cssForTD">
            <asp:Button runat="server" Width="80px" ID="Button1" Height="25px" Text="ControlText" CssClass="cssForButton"></asp:Button>
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

From the designer or Source when watching properties, the button for the events handler is not there, why?

[Watching button property there is no Event Button for the Button1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1ESh.jpg)

Comment: Did you try double clicking the button?

Comment: I can't click it because its inside the asp:table - asp:tablerow, I mean, I can only select the whole table.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. I don't know what difficulty you are having, but you should be able to select the button, or anything else you might have in the table.

Comment: I have added a label outside the table. If I mark that label from the Source and click on Design, the label is highlighted, when I do the same with the button, it highlight the whole table.
https://puu.sh/Aa6hB/e9b0398ecd.jpg